# A "free(): invalid next size (fast)" in C++

Tags: c++, memory, malloc, free

I just ran into a `free(): invalid next size (fast)` problem while writing a C++ program. And I failed to figure out why this could happen unfortunately. The code is given below.

```
bool not_corrupt(struct packet *pkt, int size)
{
    if (!size) return false;
    bool result = true;
    char *exp_checksum = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    char *rec_checksum = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    char *rec_data = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    //memcpy(rec_checksum, pkt->data+HEADER_SIZE+SEQ_SIZE+DATA_SIZE, size);
    //memcpy(rec_data, pkt->data+HEADER_SIZE+SEQ_SIZE, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        rec_checksum[i] = pkt->data[HEADER_SIZE+SEQ_SIZE+DATA_SIZE+i];
        rec_data[i] = pkt->data[HEADER_SIZE+SEQ_SIZE+i];
    }
    do_checksum(exp_checksum, rec_data, DATA_SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (exp_checksum[i] != rec_checksum[i]) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    free(exp_checksum);
    free(rec_checksum);
    free(rec_data);
    return result;
}
```

The macros used are:

```
#define RDT_PKTSIZE 128
#define SEQ_SIZE 4
#define HEADER_SIZE 1
#define DATA_SIZE ((RDT_PKTSIZE - HEADER_SIZE - SEQ_SIZE) / 2)
```

The struct used is:

```
struct packet {
    char data[RDT_PKTSIZE];
};
```

This piece of code doesn't go wrong every time. It would crash with the `free(): invalid next size (fast)` sometimes in the `free(exp_checksum);` part.

What's even worse is that sometimes what's in `rec_checksum` stuff is just not equal to what's in `pkt->data[HEADER_SIZE+SEQ_SIZE+DATA_SIZE]` stuff, which should be the same according to the watch expressions from my debugging tools. Both `memcpy` and `for` methods are used but this problem remains.

I don't quite understand why this would happen. I would be very thankful if anyone could explain this to me.

**Edit:**

Here's the do_checksum() method, which is very simple:

```
void do_checksum(char* checksum, char* data, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        checksum[i] = ~data[i];
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Thanks for all.

I switched other part of my code from the usage of STL queue to STL vector, the results turn to be cool then.

But still I didn't figure out why. I am sure that I would never pop an empty queue.

Comment: 1. Is this C or C++? 2. You are corrupting your heap. Search for invalid memory access. Use debugging tool like valgrind to help. Heap corruption probably in a different part of the code.

Comment: Have you tried running your code under Valgrind?

Comment: Why are you using `free` oh wait, why are you not using `std::string`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's actually a C++ file though I wrote this like C...  I'm not familiar with the Valgrind, but I can take a try. Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the code for do_checksum please?

Comment: it's an heap corruption, probably the problem is located elsewhere in your program (that's why heap corruption is hard to spot without tools like Valgrind.). Besides, you should write C++ facilities when programming in C++: it is a matter of style and convenience (new[] is easier to use than malloc, since it does the maths for you.).

Comment: @Als 'Cause the packet struct use char array, which is not allowed to edit by me for some reason. The char is actually just considered as a byte type in this program.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but if this code is used for some security purpose, the `break` in the last loop creates a timing vulnerability. (Besides, I agree that you should run the code with Valgrind, and that the error might be in `do_checksum()`.)

Comment: @razlebe Okay. It is a very simple function though. Check my edit.

Comment: Your `DATA_SIZE` macro looks a little suspicious. It is dividing an odd integer by 2 which will round down (truncate actually). Are you sure this isn't causing an off-by-one error in your code?

Comment: @akappa Thanks, I would take a shot for Valgrind.

Comment: Thanks for all. I switched other part of my code from the usage of STL queue to STL vector, the results turn to be cool then. But still I didn't figure out why. I am sure that I would never pop an empty queue.

Answer (score 4):

The error you report is indicative of heap corruption. These can be hard to track down and tools like valgrind can be extremely helpful. Heap corruptions are often hard to debug with a simple debugger because the runtime error often occurs long after the actual corruption.

That said, the most obvious potential cause of your heap corruption, given the code posted so far, is if `DATA_SIZE` is greater than `size`. If that occurs then `do_checksum` will write beyond the end of `exp_checksum`.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me. DATA_SIZE is a macro defined the max length in my program so the size should be less than DATA_SIZE.

Comment: And in that case you overrun the buffer exactly as I describe in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Three immediate suggestions:

1. Check for size <= 0 (instead of "!size")
2. Check for size >= DATA_SIZE
3. Check for malloc returning NULL

Comment: Item 1 is covered by item 3 and I think your inequality is the wrong way round in item 2.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Also, make sure to never send more than `RDT_PKTSIZE` as `size` to `not_corrupt()`

```
bool not_corrupt(struct packet *pkt, int size)
{
    if (!size) return false;
    if (size > RDT_PKTSIZE) return false;
    /* ... */
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet (in fact I didn't know this tool until several minutes ago), but I would like to take a try later. The size is guaranteed to be less than DATA_SIZE. However, this judgment should have been in my code. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: "size is guaranteed to be less than DATA_SIZE". There's your corruption right there! See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind is good ... but validating all your inputs and checking all error conditions is even better.

Stepping through the code in the debugger isn't a bad idea, either.

I would also call "do_checksum (size)" (your actual size), instead of DATA_SIZE (presumably "maximum size").

Answer (score 0):

> DATA_SIZE is a macro defined the max length in my program so the size
>   should be less than DATA_SIZE

even if that is true, your logic only creates enough memory to hold `size` characters.
so you should call

```
do_checksum(exp_checksum, rec_data, size);
```

and, if you do not want to use `std::string` (which is fine), you should switch from `malloc/free` to `new/delete` when talking C++